# multithreading/clusters in node.js,

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing, node-cluster

I need help on clusters in node. This is he skeleton of the program

```
global values a,b,c

function1{

get data from websocket and update the value a,b,c for every incoming message from datastream.

}

function2{
    while(1){

        do some processing using a,b,c values.
    }
}
```

the function 1 updates the data once if gets any data from the websocket stream, the data may arrive anytime- like sometimes 100 data per seconds and sometimes 2 data per 10 seconds. So the function 2 must run regardless of when the data arrives(i.e continuously)

I need to run these function 1 and 2 in parallel, like each on different cpu(or as clusters)

I tried to run on `async.parallel`, but it runs on a single thread, so until the while loop in function 2 ends function 1 will be o pause. so it cant be done using that so need to run concurrently on different threads.

I saw that cluster module, and tried to use that but, see this scenario

```
if (cluster.isPrimary) {

    function 1()

    // creating child process in other thread
    cluster.fork();
 
} else {

    function 2()
}
```

but in this case child cluster cant access global values a,b,c as they are updated/assigned using function 1, so child cluster cant access main cluster's global variable a,b,c and child's a,b,c will be empty because it doesn't run function 1 on the child thread.

What I need is to run these 2 functions in parallel on different threads. Is there any way instead on running cluster.fork running the function 2 in a different thread so that it can access global variables a,b,c.

The complete code is something like this:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

var t = 1;
var pca = "1";
var pcb = "1";
var pta = "1";
var ptb = "1";
var datato = {
    "method": "SUBSCRIBE",
    "params": [
        "trxusdc@bookTicker"
    ],
    "id": 1
}
var axios = require('axios');
var configt = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=TRXUSDT',
    headers: {}
};
var configc = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=TRXUSDT',
    headers: {}
};
async function mymodule_init0() {
    axios(configc)
        .then(function(response) {
            pca = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)).askPrice;
            pcb = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)).bidPrice;
            console.log("1");

            //--------subaxios for usdt
            axios(configt)
                .then(function(response) {
                    pta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)).askPrice;
                    ptb = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)).bidPrice;
                    console.log("2");
                    // mymodule_init1();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });


        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}


async function mymodule_init1() {

    const WS = require('ws')
    const ws = new WS('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/trxusdt@bookTicker')

    ws.on('message', function incoming(sdata) {

        if (JSON.parse(sdata).s == "TRXUSDC") {
            pca = JSON.parse(sdata).a;
            pcb = JSON.parse(sdata).b;
        }
        if (JSON.parse(sdata).s == "TRXUSDT") {
            pta = JSON.parse(sdata).a;
            ptb = JSON.parse(sdata).b;
        }



        if (t == 1) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify(datato));
            t++;
        }











    });

}


async function mymodule_init2() {





    while (1) {

        console.log(pca + " \t " + ptb + "\t" + pta + " \t " + pcb );

    }



}




setTimeout(function() {
    new Promise(resolve => {


        if (cluster.isPrimary) {
            console.log(`Primary ${process.pid} is running`);

            // Fork workers.
            for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
                cluster.fork();
            }

            cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
                console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
            });
        }
        parallel(mymodule_init1(), mymodule_init2());


    })
}, 5000);

mymodule_init0();
```

so i need to run module init 2 in a different thread, i mean that should run parallely/ seperately regardless of the function in the main thread

Comment: In short, the answer to your question is No.  The clustered processes are completely separate processes in completely different address spaces and do not share variables so cannot access the same globals.  There are lots of different ways to solve problems like this, but to know what would work in your case, we need to see the real code and understand what these variables really are, how exactly  they are updated and how often.

Comment: @jfriend00 updated the question with the code, can u check and tell me

Comment: All you're doing here is network requests and `JSON.parse()` of the results.  I don't even see why you need clustering for that since networking is all asynchronous I/O in nodejs (e.g. runs in the background).  I will assume the infinite while loop is just make-up code, not real code.  And what is `parallel()`?  Where does that come from and what does that have to do with your clustering?

Comment: The 2nd function displays the price continuously from the global variable. The first function where as updates the global variable when the stream arrives. So the second function displays regardless of the data stream received as the function 1 updates the global variables only when the stream data arrives. So I need to run this two functions at the same time regardless of the completion of these functions. So one function. Continuously displays the data other functions updates the data parallely

Comment: What is the real second function?  Surely just looping and calling `console.log()` is not the real objective here, right?  You could, instead just output to the log from the first function or generate an event that someone else can hook into anytime the variable is actually changed.  There's no need for an infinite loop here.  This is called "event-driven" programming and is the preferred model for nodejs programming.

Comment: We can offer a lot more value here if you show us the REAL problem you're trying to solve, not just a placeholder `console.log()` loop that you think might be part of a solution to your actual problem.  So, far you haven't shown anything that needs threads or clustering or anything other than a simple nodejs process using asynchronous I/O.  You appear to be making things way more complicated than need be and haven't shown any aspect of a problem that needs anything complicated.

Comment: Therw will be buy and sell http request.. if the pca pta comes to a particular number.. so still thinking on the algorithm for placing orders so haven't added that yet.. that's y for now I just want to see values continuously and take a log of that and analyse manually..that's just a backend process.. so this while loop should run continuously to send some requests to that api if the price falls to a point

Comment: multiple http requests can be in flight just fine and you don't need multiple processes for that.  That's what nodejs is particularly good at because all network activity in nodejs is asynchronous and happens in the background.  Running while loops continuously is fighting the nodejs event-driven architecture - there are much better ways to code in nodejs.  So, you should be pursuing a different strategy here rather than what you've shown so far.

Comment: If you want to run some code whenever an http request finishes and updates some data structure, you can just fire an event on an eventEmitter and have other code listening for that event so it can then decide what to do with the modified data.  This is how event-driven coding works without `while()` loops constantly checking something.  And, the event-driven architecture is massively more efficient because it's not spinning in a loop that is doing nothing useful most of the time.

Comment: ok then ill try, thanks